# fast compilation in c++

Tags: c++, compilation

I have a c++ program which has many many functions and I have different .cpp files for each of the function. From the main program, I only supply a few parameters and just call the functions. However, the compilation of the full thing takes a lot of time. For each compilation I only change a few parameters in the main program and leave all the functions as it is.
Is there anyway to speed up the compilation.?

Comment: What is your command line to compile? Are you using Makefile or some other build tool?

Comment: There may be some platform/compiler specific changes that could be suggested, but you don't specify what you are using.

Comment: What compiler are you using? You'll probably get more targeted answers if you add that detail.

Comment: I have a compile.sh file which has
g++ -o3 mainprog.cpp func1.cpp func2.cpp ..... -o output.out
and everytime I just run the compile.sh from the commandline

Comment: If you are using gcc, consider precompiled headers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/58841/precompiled-headers-with-gcc Also as others have mentioned use make. And then run it with multiple threads: make -j N

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are recompiling unnecessary code. Usually IDEs handle this automatically. Otherwise, it depends on how you compile your code. For example lines like this:

```
g++ *.cpp
```

or

```
g++ -o program a.cpp b.cpp c.cpp
```

are terribly slow, because on every compilation, you recompile everything.

If you are writing Makefiles, you should carefully write it to avoid recompilation. For example:

```
.PHONY: all
all: program

program: a.o b.o c.o
    g++ -o $@ $^ $(LDFLAGS)
%.o: %.cpp
    g++ $(CXXFLAGS) -o $@ $<
# other dependencies:
a.o: a.h
b.o: b.h a.h
c.o: c.h
```

In the above example, changing `c.cpp` causes compilation of `c.cpp` and linking of the program. Changing `a.h` causes compilation of `a.o` and `b.o` and linking of the program. That is, on each build, you compile the minimum number of files possible to make the program up-to-date.

Side note: be careful when writing Makefiles. If you miss a dependency, you will may not compile enough files and you may end up getting hard-to-spot segmentation faults (at best). Take a look also at the manual of `gcc` for `-M*` options where you can use `gcc` itself to generate the dependencies and then `include` the generated output in the `Makefile`.

Comment: yes, I understand that I am un-necessarily recompiling all the function files. I only change a few values in the main program. I have never written a make file, it will be very helpful if you can tell me how to write one, thank you.

Comment: @SthitadhiRoy, just trying searching "Makefile tutorial" and you will get many sources on that. If you want a thorough, yet easy to read explanation, you can checkout the [GNU make manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Introduction) itself.

Comment: He gave you a complete example makefile, right there. Save it to a file called `Makefile`, set the filenames correctly (`func1.o` instead of `a.o`, or whatever), look up the documentation, and then ask any specific questions you have.

Comment: @Shahbaz: regarding the dependencies, maybe indicating a tool to generate them automatically would be useful. It's so easy to get them wrong...

Comment: @MatthieuM. I agree. I believe I read somewhere that gcc (g++) can produce that, or some other program, but I don't remember. Do you know of any?

Comment: @Shahbaz: We have a perl wrapper script around gcc at work... not something I would recommend to the faint of heart. I was hoping you would know a magical solution :)

Comment: @MatthieuM. I found it [here(pdf)](http://aegis.sourceforge.net/auug97.pdf). It uses `gcc -MM <file>` to generate the dependencies. (Parent http page [here](http://miller.emu.id.au/pmiller/books/rmch/?ref=DDiyet.Com))

Comment: @MatthieuM., looking back at this conversation, the manual of `gcc` includes many `-M` variants to control what dependencies get included. For example include or exclude standard headers, missing headers etc.

Answer (score 1):

- Try to minimize the code impacted by your parameter changes, ideally only change one source file no one depens on (main.cpp).
- Check your includes: do you really need it all? Use forward declaration where possible (e.g. #include  instead of ), for your own classes, forward declare what you can.
- Try using the clang ([llvm.org](http://llvm.org)) compiler. It sometimes compiles faster than gcc (assuming you're on linux/unix) and gives more readable errors.

Edit: I was assuming you were only recompiling what's needed. As others suggested, use a buildsystem (Makefile, IDE, CMake...) to run a minimal number of compiles.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will or won't help much, but I run code through ssh and I know that it takes forever to run/compile. If you are reading from data files, instead of running entire sets of data, run only over a file or two to see your intended result. This will be a sample of your final result, but should still be accurate (just with less statistics). Once you've tweaked your code to work to your satisfaction, then run everything. **usually** you will have no problems that way, and your compile time is much quicker comparatively speaking.