# How can I use g++ to get assembly code for a C++ header (.hpp) file?

Tags: c++, assembly, header

I'm interested in trying to see the assembly code for my header file. Playing around with a simple .cpp file with a dummy main method and compiling it is easy: `g++ -S -o prog.exe main.cpp`

However, I'm going into header files now. I have a dummy header file `func.hpp` that just contains a dummy method and now I want to be able to compile it and  see its assembly in a .S file. (The main reason for this is so that if I have a more complicated function, maybe I can do some manual optimization in assembly and just build the final executable through `g++ -o prog.exe func.S main.cpp`.

However, I am not able to find sources that explain this. If I try `g++ -S -o func.S func.hpp`  I get an error message `output filename specified twice`. Can anyone help me with this?

For reference, here is func.hpp:

```
int number()
{
    return 0;
}
```

I'm also trying it out with another hpp file named struct.hpp:

```
struct Coord
{
    int x;
    int y;
};
```

Same error for both, but I want to be able to see the assembly for both headers without converting them to .cpp files (because that breaks the meaning of a header file.)

Comment: does it start working if you create a .cpp file which does _nothing_ but `#include` the header, and run `g++ -S` on that?

Comment: Actually, it does. That is BEAUTIFUL, thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could force g++ to treat the .hpp file as a C++ source file.

```
g++ -x c++ -S -o func.S func.hpp
```

The reason you get that "output filename specified twice" message is because, when passing a header file to gcc, it will assume you want to compile it into a [pre-compiled header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58841/precompiled-headers-with-gcc). Just as named, this will "compile" the headers, so a *.s file will be generated in the middle. If you pass the `-v` flag with the original command, you will see that cc1plus is called like:

```
 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/4.7.1/cc1plus
     -quiet
     -v 
     -D_GNU_SOURCE 
     func.hpp
     -quiet 
     -dumpbase func.hpp 
     -mtune=generic 
     -march=x86-64 
     -auxbase-strip func.S
     -version 
     -o func.S                # <---
     -o /tmp/ccxEg3J7.s       # <---
     --output-pch= func.S
```

So indeed `-o` is specified twice, once from your `-o` and once from the compiler.

(Of course the compiler could avoid adding the `-o /tmp/ccxEg3J7.s`, but the added complexity for this edge case isn't quite worth it.)

Comment: That's right. Otherwise, it thinks you're asking it to create a precompiled header file, so it behaves as if you'd specified `-x c++-header`. I think this question still indicates a bug in how g++ generates cc1plus commands for header files, but at least there's a workaround.