# Precompiled header via unclude directive

Tags: c, gcc, header

I have two headers `world.h` `worldw.h`.

#### world.h

```
void h_world();
```

#### worldw.h

```
void g_world();
```

After precompilation with `gcc world.h` and `gcc worldw.h` I have `world.h.gch` and `worldw.h.gch`. Futher I'm adding this precompiled headers to `main.c`:

```
#include "world.h.gch"
#include "worldw.h.gch"
....
```

But when I'm compiling this I have more than thousand errors. I'm expected that it's ok,  because precompiled header is just reduce a compile time.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Precompiled headers with GCC](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/58841/precompiled-headers-with-gcc)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of

```
#include "world.h.gch"
#include "worldw.h.gch"
```

you need

```
#include "allworld.h"
```

And in allworld.h put

```
#include "world.h"
#include "worldw.h"
```

Then precompile allworld.h ... if a .h.gch file exists, the compiler will use it; if not, it will use the .h file. You can see what is being used by compiling your source with the -H flag.

There are a number of restrictions for using a precompiled header; see http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Precompiled-Headers.html