# What does x mean before precompiled header(expecting ! - exclamation point)?

Tags: c++, compilation, precompiled-headers

I've been trying to use precompiled headers mentioned here:  [Precompiled headers with GCC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58841/precompiled-headers-with-gcc)

But after compiling my precompiled header file.h.gch, when I compile other files that include file.h with the -H option, instead of seeing

```
! /my/precompiled/header/file.h.gch
```

I'm seeing

```
x /my/precompiled/header/file.h.gch
```

Any idea what this means? The [documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Precompiled-Headers.html) doesn't mention either(! or x ).

Comment: It does mention both, in the [Preprocessor Options section](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Preprocessor-Options.html#Preprocessor-Options), under `-H`: "an invalid precompiled header file is printed with ‘...x’ and a valid one with ‘...!’ ". Did you use the same options for the precompilation as for compilation?

Comment: Ah..didn't check there.  I thought I did...I'll check...

Comment: Thanks. that was definitely the problem...